# "If anything" synonyms and examples

Tags: formality

Recently I stumbled upon this phrase "If anything". I wanted to know if it is a synonym of "On the contrary" and if so, could you write some examples? Thanks in advance people!

Comment: The phrase is used many ways, sometimes as "On the contrary." "The judge may give him 3 days of community service, if anything" means 'at most.'

Answer (score 1):

Macmillan defines "*if anything*" thusly:

> ***[if anything](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/if-anything)***
>
> PHRASE
>   used for saying how someone or something is different when you are not sure whether there really is any change or difference
>     *The situation is, if anything, worsening rather than improving.*
>     *If anything, he looks younger and healthier than he did before.*

Meanwhile, The Oxford Dictionaries say:

> ***[if anything](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/if_anything)***
>
> PHRASE
>
> Used to suggest tentatively that something may be the case (often the opposite of something previously implied)
>     *‘I haven't made much of this—if anything, I've played it down’*

So, whereas *on the contrary* implies that the former is absolutely incorrect, *if anything* is more tentative and suggestive.